# Python : Need Help About functions

Tags: python, function, arguments, typeerror, required

```
list = [1]
list2 =[1]

def all():
 num = 3
  def first(new_num): #new_num = new_index  = 3
   if num not in list:
    list.append(num)
    new_index = list.index(num)
    first(new_index) #new_index = num = 3
   else:
    second(new_num) #assign new_num to the function second()
  def second(item): #item = new_num in function first(new_num)
    print("hello" ,  item)
first()
```

all()

there is a all() at the very bottom but i dont know why its not inside for this

Comment: i have no idea why i cant call the function first(), pls help

Comment: Please use more spaces for your indentation, so that people can clearly see how each line is indented. In the long run you will make things much easier for yourself, too.

Comment: Where is `first` defined?

Answer (score 2):

This is a scoping issue.

The function `first` is inside the function `all` you cannot call `first` if it is inside `all` from outside `all`. What you *should* do is call `all` and have a call inside `all` that starts up `first` like so:

```
list = [1]
list2 =[1]

def all():
    num = 3
    def first(new_num): #new_num = new_index  = 3
        if num not in list:
            list.append(num)
            new_index = list.index(num)
            first(new_index) #new_index = num = 3
        else:
            second(new_num) #assign new_num to the function second()
    def second(item): #item = new_num in function first(new_num)
        print("hello" ,  item)
    first(num)
all()
```

Beyond that your indentation is a bit of a mess, you should be using 4 space tabs for indentation per [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: thank you so much, sorry for my messy code because i am using this for the first time, thank you once again